# Dryer exhaust pipe

Tags: dryer, vent, exhaust

M1502.4.1 Material and size. 
Exhaust ducts shall have a **smooth interior finish** and be constructed of metal having a minimum thickness of 0.0157 inches (0.3950 mm) (No. 28gage).

(a) can I use **metal** spiral pipe (not sure if it meets the "smooth" definition) ?
   e.g.,: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-4-in-x-5-ft-26-Gauge-Spiral-Pipe-26SP4X60/205330690 
(b) does it need to be 4" or can it be a larger diameter

Answer (score 1):

According to your pic yes. The smoother the pipe less chance of lint build up.Stay with the 4 inch.They make brushes to clean out easy.And fits the vent caps made for dryer.

Comment: Thank you for your reponse.
Just to clarify
It is ok to use the spiral pipe and
no its not ok to use larger diameter

Comment: Yes  to the pics you sent. My real feeling is get smoother pipe.  Your choice

Comment: that pipe is pretty smooth on the inside .... i wonder if the air flow is less turbulent in one of the two directions

Comment: Aim it to air flow ,if you want,

Comment: smaller pipe has stronger wind, you need wind to prevent lint build up. so say with 4"